# How could I modify YoastSEO Sitemaps with Wordpress? (XML files)

Tags: xml, seo, sitemap, yoast

I would like to change some priority options inside my Sitemaps generated with wordpress' plugin YoastSEO.

Is that possible, and if so, how ?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Hi Julien. Your question looks out of scope for this site. See: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). I suggest that you move your question to [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Hello Eduardo, thanks a lot to you for your answer, I will move it to the correct place :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with changing a newest generated sitemap by Yoast SEO.

Yoastseo usually save the sitemap in this directory : [www.yourwebsitename.com/sitemap_index.xml](http://www.yourwebsitename.com/sitemap_index.xml)

So you can see whole sitemap with priorities and you can just copy and paste it! I know it is some kind of nasty but it works!

Note that it works until the next sitemap YoastSEO will automatically generate!

Answer (score -1):

Priority in sitemaps there aren't relevant. It's not a factor to increase crawling or improve in rankings.

https://twitter.com/sejournal/status/1019215157791207424

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)